# Rails multiple paginations on view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination

I have a simple Article & Comments model relationship.

Presently I have:

a) an Article index view that displays a paginated list of all Articles

b) an Article show view that displays the Article and a paginated list of comments.

I would like to have a view that displays a paginated list of articles and within each article a paginated list of comments for each article.

How would this be done within the controller? For a single article and comments I can do:

```
@articles = Article.all.page(params[:page]).per_page(10)
@comments = @articles.comments.page(params[:page]).per_page(10)
```

Comment: are you using any gem for pagination?

Comment: sorry, will_paginate although I am open to changing if advised.

Answer (score 2):

create a partial page for comments...Inside articles index.html.erb file render that partial page

```
inside index.html.erb use:
<%= will_paginate @articles %>

inside _partial.html.erb use:
<%= will_paginate @comments %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to create article partial with all those comments. With partial you can just iterate all your articles and paginate them.